# Ejabbered wont start in mac os siera

Tags: ejabberd

I installed ejabbered 17.9 in mac using the .dmg file. After that I went to system preference and tried to start the server. It tries to start the server but nothing happens. After sometime it says "ejabberd is stopped". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: change log level to 5 and check the logs by repeating your steps..

Comment: Not showing anything. I have moved on to using dockers for this.